# JAXB adding attribute to element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

Here is the XML I can produce :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<students>
<student studentId="1">
    <firstName>PEsho</firstName>
    <lastName>Peshev</lastName>
    <egn>521521512</egn>
    <city>So</city>
    <mark>5.56</mark>
    <degree>
        <university>Test1</university>
    </degree>
</student>
<student studentId="1">
    <firstName>Mesho</firstName>
    <lastName>Meshev</lastName>
    <egn>521521521</egn>
    <city>Va</city>
    <mark>5.56</mark>
    <degree>
        <university>Test2</university>
    </degree>
</student>
```

What I want to do is in the degree element, the university to be a attribute, not an element. Here is the code I`m working with:
Student.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student{

@XmlAttribute
private String studentId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String egn;
private String city;
private double mark;
private Degree degree;
getters, setters ..    }
```

Students.class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "students")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Students {

@XmlElement(name = "student")
private List<Student> students = null;

public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}    }
```

The Degree.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "degree")
public class Degree {


private String university;
setters, getters
}
```

Process of marshalling :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    //Marshal the employees list in console
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, System.out);

    //Marshal the employees list in file
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, new File("file.xml"));
```

The problem is that when I`m trying to add in a Degree.class @XmlAttribute to the university field I`m getting this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
 Class has two properties of the same name "university"
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `XmlAccessType.FIELD` attribute to your Degree class.

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "degree")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Degree {

  @XmlAttribute
  private String university;
  setters, getters
}
```